# NameError: name 'training_set' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, prediction

I was trying to predict on a dataset but when I run the program it gives me the following error:

> NameError: name 'training_set' is not defined

i just try this predict code from this:

[NameError: name 'classifier' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125954/nameerror-name-classifier-is-not-defined)

but give me the error after running

(sorry for bad english)

Comment: Could you add the file?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ ... linking to code that isn't actually the code you ran is not helpful

Comment: sorry my problem is "solved" after changed some code and try it twice repeatedly, thank you for all reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you had not defined 'training_set' on the code. It should be like `training_set = insert_a_value_here` above in the code like how you already defined `test_image`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you haven't initialized it

training_set must take a value

For example, training_set can take the returning value ( tuple ) of the predefined load function that load CIFAR10 or MNIST datasets

Answer (score 0):

before predicting on the dataset these steps need to be followed

1. load the data set e.g. : `data = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')`
   now select the column from the dataset you want to predict. eg it is the column named score
2. separate the predicting column and make it your Y and rest as X .eg.
   `Y = data['score']` and
   `X = data.drop('score')`.
   the rest of the data becomes now your x.
3. make a split in your data for training and testing. you can use from
   `sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` and then do
   `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test(X,Y, test_size=0.2, random_state = 1)`

Now you have the training X as x_train and
training Y as y_train and testing X as x_test and testing Y as y_test.

4. choose the model like linear regression or some other classification model like SVM, Logisticregression. e.g
   `from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression.`
5. Run the model and fit it on your training X and training Y
   e.g
   `model = LinearRegression()`
   `model.fit(x_train, y_train)`

fitting my model on the training data.
6. predicting your score on the test data
`pred = model.predict(x_test)`

7. measuring the accuracy `import accuracy_score from sklearn.metrics`   `print(accuracy_score(y_test, pred)`