# name 'LabelEncoder' is not defined and 'KerasClassifier' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I am facing LabelEncoder is not defined and KerasClassifier is not defined problem.
i want to build a deep learning model using WSN-DS wi-fi attack dataset. Multiclass classification with Keras and Tensorflow used. Actually i am a beginer and don't have enough knowledge in python.

## multi-class classification with Keras

````
! pip install keras
! pip install sciPy
! pip install numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline```


# load dataset
```dataframe = pandas.read_csv("/WSN-DS.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:,0:4].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,4]```

# encode class values as integers
```encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)```
        
        
`NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8073498f9e21> in <module>()
      1 # encode class values as integers
----> 2 encoder = LabelEncoder()
      3 encoder.fit(Y)
      4 encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
      5 # convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)

NameError: name 'LabelEncoder' is not defined`
# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=17, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
from keras.models import load_model
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fa1808e76efa> in <module>()
      1 from keras.models import load_model
----> 2 estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
      3 kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
      4 results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
      5 print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))

NameError: name 'KerasClassifier' is not defined
````

Comment: You're in a jupyter notebook, and you've forgotten to (re)run the import cell(s) (after restarting the kernel)?

Comment: thank you. i am till facing
NameError: name 'classifier' is not defined'''

Comment: Can you please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52126042/14290681)? may help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Import LabelEncoder from Scikit-Learn library using the line below

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
```

And you're good to go!